# Make custom CLI to install npm dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I would like to create a Node CLI to generate new projects based on Node, Typescript, Jest, Express and TSLint. Basically this CLI should create a new project folder, install all the dependencies and call the `dependency --init` commands from npm, tsc and jest. It should make some changes to the config files and create some "hello world dummy files" for that new project.

A good example would be the [Vue CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

So I know how to create a CLI application but when the user calls

`myCliTool create usersProjectName`

How can I install npm dependencies for him then? Node itself doesn't know npm and I think it would be a bad idea to ship with pregenerated files and copy them into the target folder.

Comment: _Node.js_ knows [pretty well](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) _npm_ as "npm is installed with Node.js". Just launch an `npm install` command from your script.

Comment: @ TGrif thanks. By `script` you mean the commands in the package json? But how can I fire an install command during runtime?

Comment: ah I see, I can do `childProcess.execSync(...)`

Comment: No I mean directly in your script. What language do you use for your script ?

Comment: I use Typescript / Javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can do that through your script command like in script command you can run npm install for the first time when user want to create project.

Here's an example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon app.js",
    "start:prod": "export NODE_ENV=test && npm install && nodemon server/app.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test && mocha **/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
  },
```

Comment: sorry, would you mind explaining it a little more, how are the dependencies installed? I mean when I generate a `package.json` for the user, I would have to know the current versions of the dependencies, no? And how does that `npm install` gets fired?

Comment: Yes package.json will have all the information and when the script run it will get the dependencies and install it as it done with npm install when we install the dependencies of the project.

Comment: But how can I fire the `npm install` because the user shouldn't need to fire it. The CLIs I know install the dependencies while running the setup :)

Comment: like this `export NODE_ENV=test && npm install && nodemon server/app.js` the npm install run command written in this will run first after that it will execute the app.js